# On an example of an eventually oscillating function

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis

For $x\in(0,1)$, put
$$f(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}x^{2^{n}}.$$
This function possesses interesting properties. It grows monotonically from $0$ up to certain point. Then it starts to oscillate around the value $1/2$ on a left neighborhood of $1$, see Figure 1.

[image: Function $f$ on a left neigborhood of 1]

So there is at least a numerical evidence that $f(x)>1/2$ for some $x\in(0,1)$, for instance $f(0.995)\dot{=}0.500882$. Nevertheless, I did not find an analytic way to prove this observation.

Thus, I have two questions concerning the function $f$.

First, I would like to ask if there is an analytic proof (simple at best $\sim$ understandable for undergraduate students) that there exists $x\in(0,1)$ such that $f(x)>1/2$.

Second, since the limit of $f(x)$ as $x\to1-$ does not exists, I would like to know at least something about the value 
$$\limsup_{x\to1-}f(x).$$

Many thanks.

Comment: Stepping back from Robert Israel's answer a bit, you can use the functional relation x = f(x) + f(x^2) to produce values of f near 1/2 when x is near 1.  For well chosen values of x, you might show f(x) greater than 1/2.

Comment: Hmm,I just tried to get some advantage from a reformulation for $x$ near $1$, so using $x=1-t$ and then to centralize (+ smooth) the oscillation of the result around $1/2$ by writing $g(t)=((1-t)-1) - ((1-t)^2-1)+((1-t)^4-1) - ... + ... $ and $f(x)=g(1-x)+1/2 $), then expand the binomial expressions (by the powers of $(1-t)$ and collect like powers of $t$. This gives at each power of $t$ an infinite divergent series but which is alternating and can be normalized by decomposition into geometric series. This gives vanishing coefficients at the $g(t)$-series. But I've not yet arrived anywhere...

Comment: I've found heuristically more properties of $d(x)$, detailed that aspects and gave some hypothetical explanations but still cannot provide proofs. So my followup-question (and possible answeres) might be interesting. Please see here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/201098/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In addition to Noam Elkies and David Speyer's answers.  "Harder" explanation is made somewhat "softer" in http://www.maths.bris.ac.uk/~majpk/papers/37.pdf (Summability of alternating gap series, by J.P. Keating and J.B. Reade). The starting point of the argument is the Poisson summation formula in the form $$\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^nf(n)=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}((2n+1)\pi),$$
where $\hat f$ is the Fourier transform of $f$: $$\hat f(u)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{iut}f(t)dt.$$ Now consider the function $$f(t)=x^{2^{|t|}}=e^{-\lambda
2^{|t|}},$$ where $\lambda$ is introduced through $x=e^{-\lambda}$. For its  Fourier transform we have
$$\hat f(u)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{iut}e^{-\lambda
2^{|t|}}dt=2\,Re\int\limits_0^\infty e^{iut}e^{-\lambda 2^{|t|}}dt=
\frac{2}{\ln{2}}\,Re\frac{1}{\lambda^{iu/\ln{2}}}\int\limits_\lambda^\infty 
s^{(iu/\ln{2})-1}e^{-s}ds,$$ where at the last step we made a substitution $s=\lambda 2^t$. Now $$\int\limits_\lambda^\infty s^{(iu/\ln{2})-1}e^{-s}ds=
\Gamma\left(\frac{iu}{\ln{2}}\right)-\int\limits_0^\lambda 
s^{(iu/\ln{2})-1}e^{-s}ds.$$
In the last integral we can expend $e^{-s}$ in powers of $s$ and then integrate term by term. The final result is
$$\hat f(u)=\frac{2}{\ln{2}}\,Re\left[\lambda^{-iu/ln{2}}\,\Gamma\left(\frac{iu}{\ln{2}}\right)-\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\frac{\lambda^k}
{(iu/\ln{2})+k}\right].$$ Therefore the Poisson summation formula will give
$$\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2^{|n|}}=2\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2^n}-x=$$ $$\frac{2}{\ln{2}}\,Re\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty\left[\lambda^{-i(2n+1)\pi/ln{2}}\,\Gamma\left(\frac{i(2n+1)\pi}{\ln{2}}\right)-\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\frac{\lambda^k}{(i(2n+1)\pi/\ln{2})+k}\right].$$ As $f(-t)=f(t)$, we will have $\hat f(-u)=\hat f(u)$ and hence $\hat f((-2n+1)\pi)=\hat f((2n-1)\pi)$. Therefore $$\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty \hat f((2n+1)\pi)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty  \hat f((-2n+1)\pi)+
\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty  \hat f((2n+1)\pi)=2\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty  \hat f((2n+1)\pi)$$ and we get finally 
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2^n}=\frac{x}{2}+$$ 
$$\frac{2}{\ln{2}}\,Re\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\left[\lambda^{-i(2n+1)\pi/ln{2}}\,\Gamma\left(\frac{i(2n+1)\pi}{\ln{2}}\right)-\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\frac{\lambda^k}{(i(2n+1)\pi/\ln{2})+k}\right].$$ It is simple to show (see the paper) that the second term gives zero contribution in the limit $x\to 1_-$, which is equivalent to $\lambda\to 0_+$. As for the first term, introducing $$\mu=-\frac{\ln{\ln{(1/x)}}}{\ln{2}}$$ so that $\lambda=2^{-\mu}$, we will have
$$\frac{2}{\ln{2}}\,Re\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \lambda^{-i(2n+1)\pi/ln{2}}\,\Gamma\left(\frac{i(2n+1)\pi}{\ln{2}}\right)=\frac{2}{\ln{2}}\,Re\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \Gamma\left(\frac{i(2n+1)\pi}{\ln{2}}\right)e^{i(2n+1)\mu\pi}.$$ The first term oscillates with the amplitude $$ \frac{2}{\ln{2}}\left|\Gamma\left(\frac{i\pi}{\ln{2}}\right)\right|=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\ln{2}\sinh{(\pi^2/\ln{2})}}}\approx 2.75\cdot 10^{-3},$$
and it is shown in the paper that the rest is bounded in modulus by $ 1.04\cdot 10^{-9}$.

As a final remark, interestingly enough the series 
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{n^2}$$ converges to $1/2$ as $x\to 1_-$ (is Abel summable in contrast to the Hardy series considered above):  http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/98/HPL-BRIMS-98-03.pdf (Abel Summability of Gap Series, by J.P. Keating and J.B. Reade).

Comment: Anent the "final remark": Abel summability of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{n^k}$ for any
$k=1,2,3,\ldots$ follows quickly from the easy ("Abelian") direction of 
the Hardy-Littlewood result I cited.  The very fast convergence for $k=2$
is still remarkable (it follows from modularity of the theta function 
$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^n q^{n^2}$).

Answer (score 50):

This series goes back 100+ years to Hardy: "On certain oscillating series",
*Quarterly J. Math.* **38** (1907), 269-288 (pages 146-168 in
the sixth volume of Hardy's collected papers).  I did not know of this
when I posed the question as a puzzle on my webpage about 10 years ago
([puzzle 8](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/Misc/index.html#puzzles),
[solution](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/Misc/sol8.html));
I thank Tanguy Rivoal for the Hardy reference.
Shortly afterwards the question appeared in the
 [Fall
2004 issue](http://www.msri.org/ext/Emissary/EmissaryFall04.pdf) of MSRI's newsletter **EMISSARY**.

The easiest proof is surely the computational one that has been
noted here already (and which I gave in my puzzle solution):
it takes only a dozen terms of the series to confirm that $f(.995) > 1/2$,
at which point the functional equation $f(x) = x - f(x^2)$ shows that
$f(x) > f(.995) > 1/2$ when $x$ is a $(4^m)$-th root of $0.995$
for some $m=1,2,3,\ldots$ .

One can also give "harder" or "softer" explanations that may feel
more satisfactory.

On the "hard" side, as $x \rightarrow 1$ from below
the difference $f(x) - 1/2$ approaches a periodic function of
$\log_4(\log(1/x))$ that's a nearly pure sine wave of magnitude
$$
\frac2{\log 2} \, \bigl|\, \Gamma(\pi i / \log 2) \,\bigr|
= 2 \Big/ \sqrt{\log(2)\sinh(\pi^2/\log 2)} \, = \, 0.00274922\ldots
$$
(the higher harmonics' coefficients involve the values of $\Gamma$
at higher odd multiples of $\pi i / \log 2$).  Hardy obtained this by
residue calculations; it can also be recovered from Poisson summation.

On the "soft" side, the fact that $f(x)$ does not converge
as $x \rightarrow 1$ from below is a consequence of a Tauberian theorem of
Hardy and Littlewood:
*a subset $S$ of $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ has natural density* **iff**
*$S$ has Abel density, and then the two limits are equal*.
The Abel density of $S$ is $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1-} (1-x) \sum_{s\in S} x^s$
if the limit exists.  If we take
$S = \bigcup_{m=0}^\infty [2^{2m}, 2^{2m+1})$
then $(1-x) \sum_{s\in S} x^s = f(x)$; but $S$ is a standard example
of a set without natural density, so there's no Abel density either
and we're done.  Hence there is some $\epsilon > 0$ such that
$|f(x) - 1/2| > \epsilon$ for a sequence of $x$'s approaching $1$,
and then either $f(x)$ or $f(\sqrt x)$ eventually exceeds $1/2$.
I don't know whether Hardy ever observed in print that the
non-convergence of $f(x)$ is a consequence of his and Littlewood's theorem.
[I found this Tauberian theorem in
[Persi
Diaconis's doctoral thesis](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/Persi_PhDdiss.pdf) (Theorem 4 on p.37), with a reference
to page 423 of Feller's *An Introduction to Probability Theory and its
Applications, Vol. II* (Wiley, 1966).]

Comment: I am amazed with this answer. Thanks!

Comment: As usual, pretty much every answer given by Noam is amazing!

Answer (score 13):

Write $f(x) = g(t)$ where $x = \exp(-1/t)$, and $x \to 1-$ corresponds to $t \to+\infty$.  Then 
$$ g(2t) = \exp(-1/(2t)) - g(t)$$
Thus the set of limit points of $g(t)$ as $t \to \infty$ is symmetric around $1/2$.
Now
$$ g(4t) = \exp(-1/(4t)) - \exp(-1/(2t)) + g(t)$$
where $\exp(-1/(4t)) - \exp(-1/(2t))   $ is a decreasing function of $t > 0$ with $0 < \exp(-1/(4t)) - \exp(-1/(2t)) < \dfrac{1}{4t}$.  In particular, as soon as you get $g(t_1) > g(t_2)$ with $0 < t_1 < t_2$, you can conclude that
$g(2^n t_1) - g(2^n t_2) > g(t_1) - g(t_2)$ for all positive integers $n$, and
so the set of limit points has length greater than $\delta = g(t_1) - g(t_2)$.
Numerically, I get $g(52) \approx .4959378605 > g(85) \approx 0.4935023615$,
implying that the set of limit points includes at least the interval
$((1-\delta)/2,(1+\delta)/2) \approx (.4987822505, .5012177495)$.

Answer (score 11):

The point of this answer is to spell out the details behind Prof. Elkies statement that "If we change variables from $x$ to $\log_4(\log(1/x))$, we get in the limit an odd periodic oscillation of period 1". In other words, if we write $x = \exp(- 4^{-y})$, then, as $y \to \infty$, the function $f(x)$ approaches a periodic function.

Fix $y \in \mathbb{R}$. We'll study the limit of $f(\exp(-4^{-M-y}))$ as $M \to \infty$ through integers.

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
f(\exp(4^{-M+y})) &=& \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \exp(-4^{k-M-y}) - \exp(- 4^{k-M-y+1/2}) \\
&=& \sum_{j=-M}^{\infty} \exp(-4^{j-y}) - \exp(4^{j-y+1/2}). \\
\end{array}$$

Setting $h(y) = \exp(-4^{-y}) - \exp(-4^{-y+1/2})$, we see that
$$\lim_{M \to \infty} f(\exp(4^{-M+y})) = \sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} h(y+j) =: g(y).$$
The function $h$ decays rapidly as $y \to \pm \infty$, so the sum converges. Here is a plot of $h$:
[image]

The function $g$ is clearly periodic, and its Fourier expansion can be found by [Poisson summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula). The constant term is
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(y) dy =\lim_{T \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{T} \exp(-4^{-y}) - \exp(-4^{1/2-y}) dy = \lim_{T \to \infty} \int_{T-1/2}^T \exp(-4^{-y}) dy = \frac{1}{2}$$
explaining why the function oscillates around $1/2$.

At this point the surprise that $\lim_{x \to 1^{-1}} f(x)$ doesn't exist turns into the extremely plausible fact that the Fourier coefficients $\int h(y) e^{(2 \pi i)k y } dy$ are nonzero. I don't see how to do the integrals in closed form, but numeric computation gives
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(y) \cos(2 \pi y) dy \approx -0.00137235.$$

Answer (score 7):

Here's an unenlightening proof of part $1$, assuming you believe my computer's ability to multiply six-digit numbers correctly.  If not you could do the $22$ six-digit multiplications by hand.  If you run the python program below, it prints $500715$.  At each step it computes integers which are lower and upper bounds to $10^6x^{2^n}$.  It does the alternating sum in the pessimal way, adding lower bounds and subtracting upper bounds, for the terms $n=0$ to $n=10$.  It then bounds the magnitude of the rest of the series as being less than the geometric series
$x^{2^{11}}(1+x+x^2+\ldots) = \frac{x^{2^{11}}}{1-x} \leq 2x^{2^{11}}$ and subtracts an upper bound for this.

```
precision = int(1e6)
x = int(precision*0.995)

up = x
low = x

z = 0

for n in xrange(11):
    if n % 2:
        z -= up
    else:
        z += low
    up = up*up/precision + 1
    low = low*low/precision

print z - 2*up
```

Answer (score 7):

*This is more an extended comment than an answer.*

I refer to your function 
$$ f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k x^{2^k} \qquad \qquad 0 \lt x \lt 1 \tag 1$$ and as generalization
$$ f_b(x)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k x^{b^k} \qquad \qquad 1 \lt b \tag 2$$

> ***[update 8'2016]*** The same values as for the function $g(x)$ as described below one gets seemingly simply by the completing function of $f(x)$ -the sum where the index goes to negative infinity, such that, using Cesarosummation $\mathfrak C$ for the alternating divergent series in $h(x)$ , we have that
>   $$h(x) \underset{\mathfrak C}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k x^{2^{-k}} \qquad \qquad    \underset{\text{apparently } }{=} -g(x) \tag{2.1} $$
>    *(Note, the index starts at $1$)* .
>   The difference-curve $d(x)$ as shown in the pictures of my original answer below occurs then similarly by
>    $$d(x)= h(x)+f(x) \underset{\mathfrak C}= \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^k x^{2^k} \tag {2.2}$$
>   Using the derivation provided in @Zurab Silagadze's answer I get the alternative description (using the constants $l_2=\log(2)$ and $\rho = \pi i/l_2$ )
>   $$ d^*(x) \underset{
>  \lambda=\log(1/x) \\
>  \tau = \lambda^\rho}{=}  \quad {2\over l_2 } \sum_{\begin{matrix}k=0 \\ j=2k+1 \end{matrix}}^\infty    \Re\left[{\Gamma( \rho \cdot j ) \over \tau^j}\right] \tag {2.3}$$
>   which agrees numerically very well with the direct computation of $d(x)$.
>   *(I don't have yet a guess about the relevance of this, though, and whether $d(x)$ has also some other, especially closed form, representation)*
>   ***[end update]***

To get possibly more insight into the nature of the "wobbling" I also looked at the (naive) expansion into double-series.
By writing $u=\ln(x)$ and expansion of the powers of $x$ into exponential-series we get the following table:
$$ \small \begin{array} {r|rr|rrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
 +x & & +\exp(u) &&= +(& 1&+u&+u^2/2!&+u^3/3!&+...&) \\
 -x^2 & & -\exp(2u)& &= -(& 1&+2u&+2^2u^2/2!&+2^3u^3/3!&+...&) \\
 +x^4 & & +\exp(4u)& &= +(& 1&+4u&+4^2u^2/2!&+4^3u^3/3!&+...&) \\
 -x^8 & & -\exp(8u)& &= -(& 1&+8u&+8^2u^2/2!&+8^3u^3/3!&+...&) \\
 \vdots & & \vdots & \\ \hline
 f(x) & & ??? &g(x) &=( & 1/2 & +{1 \over1+2} u &+{1 \over1+2^2} {u^2 \over 2!} &+{1 \over1+2^3} {u^3 \over 3!} & +... &)
 \end{array}$$ 
where $g(x)$ is computed using the closed forms of the alternating geometric series along the columns.
The naive expectation is, that $f(x)=g(x)$ but which is not true. However, $$g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty {(\ln x)^k\over (1+2^k) k! } \tag 3 $$ is still a meaningful construct: it defines somehow a monotonuous increasing "core-function" for the wobbly function $f(x)$ , perhaps so to say a functional "center of gravity".
The difference $$d(x)=f(x)-g(x) \tag 4$$ 
captures then perfectly the oscillatory aspect of $f(x)$. Its most interesting property is perhaps, that it seems to have perfectly constant amplitude ($a \approx 0.00274922$) . The wavelength however is variable and well described by the transformed value $x=1-4^{-y}$ as already stated by others. With this transformation the wavelength approximates $1$ very fast and very well for variable $y$.

For the generalizations $f_b(x)$ with $b \ne 2$ the amplitude increases with $b$, for instance for $b=4$ we get the amplitude $A \approx 0.068$ and for $b=2^{0.25}$ is $a \approx 3e-12$

---

Here are pictures of the function $f(x)$, $g(x)$ and $d(x)= f(x)-g(x)$ :
[image: bild1]

The blue line and the magenta line are nicely overlaid over the whole range $0<x<1$ and the amplitude of the red error-curve (the $y$-scale is at the right side) seems ***to be constant***.
In the next picture I rescaled also the x-axis logarithmically (I've used the hint from Robert Israel's anwer to apply the exponentials to base $4$):
[image: bild2]

Having the x-axis a logarithmic scale, the curve of the $d(x)$ looks like a perfect sine-wave (with a slight shift in wave-length). If this is true, then because $g(0)=1/2$ the non-vanishing oscillation of $f(x)$, focused in the OP, when $x \to 1$ is obvious because it's just the oscillation of the $d(x)$-curve...
For the more critical range near $y=0.5$ I've a zoomed picture for this:
[image: bild3]

But from  here my expertise is exhausted and I've no tools to proceed. First thing would be to look at the Fourier-decomposition of $d(x)$ which might be simpler than that of $f(x)$. Possibly we have here something like in the Ramanujan-summation of divergent series where we have to add some integral to complete the divergent sums, but I really don't know.

Answer (score 7):

A reference to this answer is Hardy's 'Divergent Series'. Although we do not obtain a magnitude of oscillation, the divergence of $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1-} f(x)$ follows from the following method. Here, we do not need numerical values, nor the Tauberian theorems, just a little bit of Complex Analysis.

After solving [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296066/evaluate-lim-x-to1-left-sum-n-0-infty-leftx2n-right-log-2-f/2869547#2869547), I realized that the same method applies here.

Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n x^{2^n}$ as given. Let $g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\log x)^n}{(2^n+1)n!}$. Then 
$$
f(x)+f(x^2)=x, \ \ g(x)+g(x^2)=x.
$$ 
Let $\Phi(x)=f(x)-g(x)$. Then we have
$$
\Phi(x)=-\Phi(x^2)=\Phi(x^4).
$$
If we prove that $\Phi$ is not a constant, then it follows that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1-} f(x)$ does not exist.

Taking the principal branch of logarithm, we see that $\Phi(z)=f(z)-g(z)$ is analytic on $D=\{z: |z|<1, \ \ z\notin (-1,0]\}$.

Let $z=re^{2\pi i /3}$, and let $r\rightarrow 1-$. Then we have
$$
\Im(f(z))\rightarrow \infty, \textrm{ hence }|f(z)|\rightarrow\infty,
$$
$$
g(z) \textrm{ is bounded.}
$$
Thus, $\Phi(z)$ is not a constant on $D$. Hence, $\Phi(x), \ \ 0<x<1$ is not a constant.

**Added 3/29/2020**

It can also be proved by this method that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}g(x)$ does not exist.